# What is the fastest engine for drawing large numbers of semitransparent trianges?

Tags: web, graphics, 3d, gpu

I enjoy computer graphics.

I was wondering what the fastest engine was with the following functionality:

Draws triangles with 4 color channels rgba and allows for the drawing of point and directional lights.

Texturing would be a cool additional feature, but again I am looking for the fastest engine, not the most functional. Camera animation and object animation will be imperative.

Finally there are really 2 answers for this question, 1 for general development and one for web, but if you can only speak to one or the other your contributions will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

There are quite a lot of engines that do the job. One of the most known is for example Unity, where you also have tons of other features in good performance.

But I think you are not really looking for an engine but an API. Examples are OpenGL or DirectX (already mentioned). OpenGL even has a specific web content (WebGL).

There is one more problem: the triangles should be semitransparent. What is missing in the other answer is the question if the triangles are already ordered. OpenGL for example is good in rendering objects where it does not matter which triangle is nearest to the viewer. It "searches" this one on the fly and shows only the triangle that is visible. But with semitransparent triangles it is possible to see different triangles overlapping each other and therefore it is not only necessary to know which triangle is in the front, but which triangle comes directly after that and so on. OpenGL offers blending for this feature, but is necessary to order the semitransparent triangles manually before rendering. This is called the Painters Algorithm. While Sorting of objects is a complex problem, exspecially with a large number of objects, this could take quite long time.

For this there is another solution called "depth peeling". The idea is to render all triangles multiple times with OpenGL. The first time you get all the triangles which are in the front. Now you render all triangles again, but without the triangles in the front. This results in the second nearest triangles to the viewer. After that all triangles are rendered again, but without the first two "peels", which results in the third nearest triangles and so on. This is expensive because everything has to get rendered multiple times, but in cases where there is a very large number of triangles this is faster than sorting (and more precise due to overlapping triangles). In most cases four peels are enough for good results. For further read I suggest the following paper of Everitt: http://gamedevs.org/uploads/interactive-order-independent-transparency.pdf

Comment: Upvote for the reference. I used this technique a lot in the 90's when I wrote a lot of code to do 3D-graphics. Had no idea it had a name - "depth peeling". And that is a good name.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is probably [OpenGL](https://www.opengl.org). In the case of the web, you could use [WebGL](https://www.khronos.org/webgl/) and in the case of native desktop or mobile development you could directly use OpenGL.

Comment: Aight so I have some experience with webgl with 3js see https://krewn.github.io unfortunately something about it only works in chrome... As far as OpenGL vs. WebGL What is the relationship/ and differences?

Comment: The relationship is that they're based on the same API. The difference is that OpenGL is for the desktop and WebGL is for the browser. One problem with WebGL is that it's not supported everywhere, and users may have to explicitly turn it on in their browsers.

Comment: For the web, I'm not aware of anything. For the desktop there are other alternatives like DirectX, Vulkan, and Metal. I believe that Vulkan and Metal are also available on some mobile devices. I'm not sure about DirectX.

Comment: yeah windows phones use DirectX Graphics Infrastructure (DXGI) APIs https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj207010%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

Comment: OpenGL does only support semitransparent triangles in a specific order. If the triangles are not ordered, then it becomes quite a mess,